.NET 7 Maui Application Page opens in Debug mode but crashes in Release mode
I have a .NET Maui Project built on .NET 7. It works seamlessly in Debug mode, but gives me the following error message when opening a page in Release mode
System.InvalidCastException: Arg_InvalidCastException at CommunityToolkit.Maui.Extensions.ValueConverterExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at MauiAttributeProgrammer.Views.MainPage_PickFirmwarePackageFrame.InitializeComponent()
   at MauiAttributeProgrammer.Views.DFUPage.InitializeComponent()
   at MauiAttributeProgrammer.Views.DFUPage..ctor()
   at System.Reflection.ConstructorInvoker.InterpretedInvoke(Object , Span1 , BindingFlags )
   Exception_EndOfInnerExceptionStack
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceMono(Boolean , Boolean )
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type , Boolean , Boolean )
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type )
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Routing.TypeRouteFactory.GetOrCreate(IServiceProvider services)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Routing.GetOrCreateContent(String route, IServiceProvider services)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellSection.GetOrCreateFromRoute(String route, ShellRouteParameters queryData, IServiceProvider services, Boolean isLast, Boolean isPopping)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellSection.GoToAsync(ShellNavigationRequest request, ShellRouteParameters queryData, IServiceProvider services, Nullable1 animate, Boolean isRelativePopping)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellNavigationManager.GoToAsync(ShellNavigationParameters shellNavigationParameters, ShellNavigationRequest navigationRequest)
   at MauiAttributeProgrammer.Views.OptionsPage.FirmwareBtn_ClickedAsync(Object sender, EventArgs e)

I use the same exact XAML, View and ViewModel in another app and it works as expected in Release mode. Any idea where to look for the error?
This is the frame within a page that is causing the issue. When I remove the frame, the page shows in Release mode.
MainPage_PickFirmwarePackageFrame.xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MauiAttributeProgrammer.ViewModels"
         BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Back}"
         Shell.NavBarIsVisible="false"
         xmlns:helper="clr-namespace:MauiAttributeProgrammer.Converters"
         x:Class="MauiAttributeProgrammer.Views.MainPage_PickFirmwarePackageFrame">
<ContentView.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <helper:InvertedBooleanConverter x:Key="InvertedBooleanConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentView.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Text="Firmware Package"
           Grid.Row="0"
           FontSize="10"
           HorizontalOptions="Start"
           Opacity="0.5" />
    <Label Text="Tap to edit"
           BindingContext="{x:Static viewModels:DFUPageViewModel.Instance}"
           IsVisible="{Binding HasStarted, Converter={StaticResource InvertedBooleanConverter}}"
           Grid.Row="0"
           FontSize="10"
           HorizontalOptions="End"
           Opacity="0.5" >
    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="FirmwareFrame_TappedAsync" />
    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
    </Label>
    <Frame Grid.Row="1"
           BackgroundColor="Black">
    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="FirmwareFrame_TappedAsync" />
    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        <StackLayout
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            BindingContext="{x:Static viewModels:FirmwarePackageViewModel.Instance}">
            <Label Text="{Binding SelectedFirmwareFile.Name, FallbackValue='No file currently selected'}"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            <Label Text="{Binding SelectedFirmwareFile.Length, StringFormat='{0} bytes', FallbackValue='? bytes'}"
                   FontAttributes="Italic"
                   Opacity="0.4"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   FontSize="10" />
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>

</Grid>

xaml.cs for the xaml
using MauiAttributeProgrammer.HelperClass;
using MauiAttributeProgrammer.ViewModels;
using Mopups.Interfaces;

 namespace MauiAttributeProgrammer.Views
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MainPage_PickFirmwarePackageFrame
{
    public MainPage_PickFirmwarePackageFrame()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    async void FirmwareFrame_TappedAsync(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
    {
        int file = await FirmwarePackageViewModel.Instance.PickFileAsync();
        if (file == 1)
        {
            ToastMsg.ShowMessageCV(this, "Not an Accepted File Type");
        }
        else { return; }
    }
}
}

FirmwarePackageViewModel
using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;
 using Microsoft.Maui;
 using Laerdal.Dfu;

 namespace MauiAttributeProgrammer.ViewModels
 {
public class FirmwarePackageViewModel :      HelperClass.BindableObject
{
    public string fileUrl = null;
    #region Singleton

    /// <summary>
    /// Singleton instance
    /// </summary>
    public static FirmwarePackageViewModel Instance => _instance ?? (_instance = new FirmwarePackageViewModel());

    public static FirmwarePackageViewModel _instance;

    #endregion
    public FileInfo SelectedFirmwareFile
    {
        get => GetValue<FileInfo>();
        set
        {
            if (SetValue(value))
            {
                fileUrl = value?.FullName;
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task<int> PickFileAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            bool apiCheck = true;
            // Check API level of Android device
         #if ANDROID
            apiCheck =             (int)Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt <              (int)Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Tiramisu;
        #endif
            if (apiCheck) // API level 33
            {
                if (await             Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>() != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                    if (await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>() != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                        return 2;
            }

            var options = new PickOptions
            {
                PickerTitle = "Please select a zip file",
            };
            var result = await FilePicker.PickAsync(options);
            if (result.ContentType == "zip" || result.ContentType == "application/zip")
            {
                var newFilePath = await CopyFile(result);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newFilePath))
                    SelectedFirmwareFile = new FileInfo(newFilePath);
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return 2;
            // The user canceled or something went wrong
        }
    }

    private async Task<string> CopyFile(FileResult fileResult)
    {
        var outputFilePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, fileResult.FileName);
        if (File.Exists(outputFilePath))
            File.Delete(outputFilePath);

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(outputFilePath, FileMode.Create))
        using (var stream = await fileResult.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < stream.Length; i++)
            {
                fileStream.WriteByte((byte)stream.ReadByte());
            }

            fileStream.Close();
            stream.Close();
        }

        return outputFilePath;
    }
}
 }

This is where the "frame" is applied in a xaml
DFUPage.xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <ContentPage      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MauiAttributeProgrammer.Views"
         xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MauiAttributeProgrammer.ViewModels"
         BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Back}"
         Shell.NavBarIsVisible="false"
         x:Class="MauiAttributeProgrammer.Views.DFUPage"
         xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls" xmlns:xct="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
         ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"
         Title="DFUPage">
<ScrollView>
<Grid Padding="20" RowSpacing="12">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                     Grid.Row="0"
                     Margin="-10,-20,0,0">
            <Button Text="❮"
                    BackgroundColor="{StaticResource BackDark}"
                    Clicked="BackBtn_ClickedAsync"
                    FontSize="Title"
                    WidthRequest="40"
                    HeightRequest="50"
                    Padding="10,0,10,0"
                    />
        </StackLayout>
    <views:MainPage_PickFirmwarePackageFrame Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Button Text="Start"
            Grid.Row="2"
            HeightRequest="40"
            BackgroundColor="Black"
            Clicked="StartButton_ClickedAsync"
            FontAttributes="Bold" />
</Grid>
</ScrollView>

using MauiAttributeProgrammer.Converters.Base;

 namespace MauiAttributeProgrammer.Converters
{
public class InvertedBooleanConverter : BaseConverter<bool, bool>
{
    protected override bool ConvertFrom(bool value, object parameter)
    {
        return !value;
    }

    protected override bool ConvertBackTo(bool value, object parameter)
    {
        return !value;
    }
}

}

This error seems to be related to "binding", and you can refer to this case: ` System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'. In addition, could you proivde some code to repoduce the question?

@JianweiSun-MSFT I added the code where the issue arises.

@JianweiSun-MSFT And a new stack trace that had more info

for debugging purposes please remove InvertedBooleanConverter and let use know if the app crash or no in release mode. Also is InvertedBooleanConverter defined in Community toolkit package or it is your definition? because i see it namespace looks like it is not coming from that package

@Cfun I removed it and replaced it with a True constant and everything works as expected. This is my code for that file.

please don't post code i na comment instead post it by editing your question, so when you remove that converter the app doesn't crash anymore in RELEASE mode right ?

Yes you are correct. I placed the code up in the question sorry about that

@Cfun I forgot to tag you

@Cfun I will try and implement this tomorrow and get back!

@minimite Any update since then ?

You are likely having an issue with the linker removing code thinking it is unused while in fact it is being used in xaml for example.
Try to decorate your InvertedBooleanConverter and BaseConverter classes with the attribute [Preserve(AllMembers = true)], also check https://stackoverflow.com/a/78313278/ and let us know if any of the actions did solve your issue.
